# how to get key from map in flutter at required position's key in flutter

Tags: flutter

Its not easy for me to explain what I want and thats why I have created this demo to make my point clear...

I have a data mymap which key is based on random number and value is bool

in my list tile of listview builder, I want sometime value and sometime key in it's
title,subtitle,trailing,leading

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {



  Map<String,dynamic> mymap={
    '${Random().nextInt(255)}':false,
    '${Random().nextInt(255)}':true,
    '${Random().nextInt(255)}':true,
    '${Random().nextInt(255)}':false,
   

  };

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){

          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
                //firstkey + value
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              //secondkey +value
            ),

            leading: Text(
              //thirdkey only
            ),
            trailing: Text(
              //fourthkey's value
            ),
          );

        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get keys like here:

```
List keys = myMap.keys.toList();
```

And get access to keys in list tile like here:

```
Text(keys[2].toString()), // get key from list index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List` to make sure of getting sorted value.

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Map<String, bool>> mymap = [
    {'${Random().nextInt(255)}': false},
    {'${Random().nextInt(255)}': true},
    {'${Random().nextInt(255)}': true},
    {'${Random().nextInt(255)}': false},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title:
                  Text("${mymap.first.keys.first} ${mymap.first.values.first}"),
              subtitle: Text("${mymap[1].keys.first} ${mymap[1].values.first}"),
              leading: Text("${mymap[2].keys.first}"),
              trailing: Text("${mymap[3].values.first}"),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Perhaps A model class List is better.

Comment: No..my map is not a list,,thats the problem.....its a single data

Comment: and I can't change to list of map...as it affects many places

Comment: Is it ok If I convert map to list

Comment: No...I don't want to change Map to List<Map>

Comment: Try mohammad esmaili methods, also map doesnt provide index If i am not wrong

Comment: I searched for key's index but not found...okay will try with mohammed's method

Comment: and pls can u check my question 'How to use function inside stream builder for fetching user detail based on userid in flutter?' as I am stuck there for moving advance to next chapter....actually so far I have used sql that has easy approach of inner join and outer join, but here I m completely failing to fetch data from one collection with other